# generically disable multiple buttons based on evaluating value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a a number of buttons that a user can click on in response to a question.  Some of the buttons are correct answers, and others are incorrect.  If the button is an incorrect answer, the button remains live, but a counter increments counting wrong answers.  If the button is a correct answer, then I want to increment the correct answer count, change the button styling, and disable the button. Code snippet (html):

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div>
    Right answers: {{ right_answers }}
  </div>

  <div>
    Wrong answers: {{ wrong_answers }}
  </div>

  <button ng-style="answer1Style" ng-click="clickThis('answer1')" ng-disabled='answer1'> Answer1 </button>
  <button ng-style="answer2Style" ng-click="clickThis('answer2')" ng-disabled='answer2'> Answer2 </button>
  <button ng-style="answer3Style" ng-click="clickThis('answer3')" ng-disabled='answer3'> Answer3 </button>
  <button ng-click="clickThis('wrong1')" ng-disabled='wrong1'> Wrong1 </button>
  <button ng-click="clickThis('wrong2')" ng-disabled='wrong2'> Wrong2 </button>
  <button ng-click="clickThis('whatever')" ng-disabled='whatever'> Whatever </button>

</div>
```

Code snippet (controller):

```
var myCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.right_answers = 0;
  $scope.wrong_answers = 0;

  $scope.answers = ['answer1','answer2','answer3'];

  $scope.clickThis = function(answer) {
    if ($scope.answers.indexOf(answer) != -1) {
      $scope.right_answers += 1;
      switch(answer){
        case 'answer1': 
          $scope.answer1 = true;
          $scope.answer1Style = {'background-color':'green', 'color':'white'};
          break;
        case 'answer2': 
          $scope.answer2 = true;
          $scope.answer2Style = {'background-color':'green', 'color':'white'};
          break;
        case 'answer3': 
          $scope.answer3 = true;
          $scope.answer3Style = {'background-color':'green', 'color':'white'};
          break;
      };
    }
    else {
      $scope.wrong_answers += 1;
    };    
  };

};
```

My question is, is there a way to make this more generic, where I don't have to use a CASE and include a $scope for each individual answer in order to disable it (or change the style for that matter), i.e. `ng-disabled="answer1"`, `ng-disabled="answer2"`, `$scope.answer1`, `$scope.answer2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `$event` object as argument of `ngClick` directive.

```
<button ng-click="clickThis($event, 'answer')"> Answer </button>
```

Then you will be able to do manipulations with target element in `$scope.clickThis` function

```
$scope.clickThis = function(event, answer) {
  if ($scope.answers.indexOf(answer) != -1) {
    $scope.rightAnswers += 1;
    element = angular.element(event.target);
    element.css({'color': 'white', 'background-color': 'green'});
    element.prop('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $scope.wrongAnswers += 1;
  };
}
```

Example: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/ilXTyOz9OSCRQArDNv4c?p=preview)